# how to call assembly program inside c program- Visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, optimization, assembly

I need to call inline asm function in my c program "mainFunction.c"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double inline __declspec (naked) __fastcall sqrt14(double n)
{
    _asm fld qword ptr [esp+4]
    _asm fsqrt
    _asm ret 8
}

int main(){
   double a=10.5;
   double b;
   b=sqrt14(a);
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program I am getting syntax errors.
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  
error C2085: 'sqrt14' : not in formal parameter list
error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

if I change the file name to "mainFunction.cpp" means the program works fine.

Comment: When posting questions about compiler errors, it helps a lot if you could provide the *complete* and *unedited* error log. And please don't post it as a comment, *edit the question* to include it. Also, please mark out in the source *where* those errors are.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which errors you got, but the function definition seems a little suspicious. See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx

> > The compiler cannot generate an inline function for a function marked with the naked attribute, even if the function is also marked with the __forceinline keyword.

It also doesn't make a lot of sense to try stripping a function that's going to be inlined anyway, inlining already does most of the job for you.

Comment: Yes, removing `inline` does work, but it's true, the error message from the compiler is not very clear. +1 for that.